# What does @ do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've tried searching all over the place and even read through some chunks of the ECMA specification, and I cannot for the life of me find anything to explain what the at symbol (@) does in JavaScript. Can anyone out there please help me understand this little guy?

Doc I was reading : http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In what context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You won't find it in ECMA-262. You want [ECMA-357](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/Ecma-357.pdf).

### § 11.1.1 Attribute Identifiers

> An `AttributeIdentifier` is used to identify the name of an XML attribute. It evaluates to a value of type `AttributeName`. The preceding “@” character distinguishes a  XML  attribute from a XML element with the same name. This `AttributeIdentifier` syntax was chosen for consistency with the familiar XPath syntax.

Comment: Thank you sincerely for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 3):

@ doesn't do anything in ECMA262. The document uses it as a placeholder for different operators that use the same syntax. For example, they describe compound assignment such as `foo @= bar` instead of indicating all of the compound assignment operators.

Compound assignment operators are those such as `x += 1`, except there are quite a few of them, thus, use of the @ sign to represent all of them symbolically in the manual only, nothing in code.

As Eli Grey points out, this is a feature that exists in *[EcmaScript for XML](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/E4X)*, often nicnamed *E4X*, offically named ECMA-357.

It's important to note that E4X support is presently not common everywhere, and not really the most suitable standard "for the open web", as the WikiPedia article states:

> E4X **is supported** by Mozilla's **Rhino**, used in **OpenOffice**.org and several other projects, and **SpiderMonkey, used in Firefox, Thunderbird, and other XUL-based applications.** It is also supported by Tamarin, the JavaScript engine used in the Flash virtual machine. It is **not supported** by Nitro (**Safari**), V8 (Google **Chrome**), **Opera**, nor **Internet Explorer**.[1](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/E4X)

From the E4X example on the page,

You can assign a variable some XML data (in much the same way we can use JSON syntax to assign objects)

```
var sales = <sales vendor="John">
    <item type="peas" price="4" quantity="6"/>
    <item type="carrot" price="3" quantity="10"/>
    <item type="chips" price="5" quantity="3"/>
  </sales>;
```

Then, to get an attribute value, such as the value of "vendor", we can do

```
alert( sales.@vendor );
```

And get back "John" in the alert box.